# sub-submenu walker method

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i have a walker class applied for my submenu but how do i get the sub-submenu item into this code?

below is my code

functions.php

```
<?php    
class wp_submenu_class extends Walker_nav_menu {    
  function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {    
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);    
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"submenu\">\n";    
  }    
}   
?>
```

header.php

```
<div class="navi">
<?php  wp_nav_menu( array(    
    'menuitems' => 'mymenu',    
    'container'       => '',     
    'container_id'    => '',    
    'menu_class'      => 'topmenu',    
    'menu_id'         => '',    
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',    
    'walker' => new wp_submenu_class() ));     
 ?>    
</div>
```

Comment: Follow this:--[Docs1](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_Custom_Walker_Function) **OR** [Doc2](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker)

Comment: thanx akshay...but i am a newbie and that flew over my head... could u possibly help me with the code?

Answer (score 0):

> you haven't specified an end_lvl for your class.

```
<?php  wp_nav_menu( array(    
                        'menu' => 'Menu 1',  // REPLACE NAME WITH YOUR MENU
                        'container_class' => 'menu-header',
                        'menu_class' => 'nav-menu',
                        'depth'=> 3, // CHANGE THE VALUE WHICH LAVEL YOU CAN DISPLAY.
                        'menuitems' => 'mymenu',    
                        'container'       => '',     
                        'container_id'    => '',    
                        'menu_class'      => 'menu-header', // MENU CLASS   
                        'menu_id'         => '',    
                        'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',    
                        'walker' => new wp_submenu_class() //function
                        ));     
?>

class wp_submenu_class extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
  function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"submenu\">\n";
  }
  function end_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: what about the sun-submenu...how do i get that working

Comment: this function add on function.php you can use firebug in firefox key press F12 see the html.

Comment: i have the submenu working but the submenu for the submenu doesn't display how doi get that to display?

Comment: thanx :)...when it comes to depth 3 the submenu goes behind the submenu of depth2 how can i get it to display in the side of the concerned parent